# Advanced Word Filter

Tags: php

I really need a good bad word filter for my script. I already have an array of the bad words. But my problem was that it detected bad words in other words like say "test" was a bad word and you said "testing" it would still count it as a cuss word. On my second try i fixed the detect words in other words but people could bypass it etc by saying @test and 'cusswordhere'.

Is there any thing i can do to fix this?

My Code:

```
  function censor($message) {
            $badwords = $this->censor; //array containing bad words
            $message = @preg_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]','',strtolower(' '.$message.' '));
            foreach($badwords as $bad) {
                $bad = trim($bad);
                if(strpos($message.' ', $bad.' ')!==false) {
                    if(strlen($bad)>=2) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }   
            }

    }
```

Currently it doesn't detect words in other words but you can bypass it by saying stuff like @cusshere  "cusshere" etc, is there anything i can do to fix this?

Comment: You are already removing characters like `@` and `"`, so how can a user bypass that?

Answer (score 0):

This would catch *any* occurrence of a work on your list, no matter where it falls in the message; probably too restrictive, but might be helpful:

```
function censor($message) {
  foreach($this->censor as $word){
    if(false !== stripos($message, $word)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```